# Visual Studio 2017 Load Test “No such host is known” with remote controller

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, performance-testing, load-testing, web-performance

**Issue:** When running a load test from my client, with a remote controller on a second machine and a remote agent on a third machine, I receive the following error

> Error 8/28/2017 6:59:18 AM    Failed to queue test run '': No
>   such host is known.

- I have Visual Studio 2017 on my client. The 2017 Test Controller is installed and configured on a second machine running Windows Server 2016. The 2017 Test Agent is installed and configured on a third machine running Windows Server 2016. The Test DB is on SQL Express on the second machine, same box as the Test Controller.
- The configuration of all items worked fine (Test Controller, Test Agent, etc) without any issues or errors.
- I installed VS 2017 on the Test Controller machine and was able to run tests without issue.
- I can debug from my client without issue, but when I try RUNNING the test, it states the error above.
- I can "manage test controllers" and see my controller, as well as the test agent listed, all in "ready status." Additionally, setting the LoadTest DB has a "test connection successful" message when setting it up.
- My current .testsettings file is set up with the role to have all agents associated with my test controller be for running tests. It is set as the active test setting.
- I've put the FQDN in all the setup, and added all the associated machines to the host files on each box.
- The firewall has been disabled on every box to try that to no avail. Network Sharing is on, Printer sharing is on, ports are open. Verified this with port scanners, checking settings on the servers, and I can ping and NSLookUp each box from each other.
- I've tried recording brand new tests and running existing tests (ones that worked if I ran VS2017 on the Test Controller) to no avail.

At this point, I'm really not sure what else to do or try, nor what other information to provide. I'm dumbfounded as I've read all the troubleshooting docs on network permissions, local permissions, etc. The only thing I haven't done is made an AD group for the machines involved and adding those to local admin groups.

If anyone could help, PLEASE, feel free to ask questions and I'll do my best to provide the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm these:

- Create a load test in VS17.
- On one computer, you configure a test controller in a domain.
- On another computer, you configure a test agent in a different domain.

  **Note:** The two domains trust one another.
- You run the load test on the test controller computer and the test agent computer.

**Edit:**

- Connect your controller computer and get its *hostname*.
- Go to host file *"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"*.
- And add *hostname* as IP address.
- At last VS17 will successfully connected to your controller.

Comment: Yes, I put that in my original question. I can run a load test with the setup | Client/Test Controller on same machine. Test Agent on new machine.

Comment: If you have entries there your client machine sends the computer name it finds in the first entry to the controller as its name.

Comment: If I have entries where? My host file? I set up my host file with FQDN to ensure they can reach each other, and all the setup/configuration was with FQDN too just in case.

Comment: As I just stated, I already entered those in my host files, so that isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is that there was no route BACK to the client. I needed to add a fully qualified entry for the cient to the hosts file on the controller. This was compunded by using a VPN to Azure.

To clarify you need the FQDN of your client added to the hosts file of your controller.